# Prove;$\left|\sum\limits_{n \in I}Re(\lambda(n))\right|\le 1 \implies \sum\limits_{n \in I} \left|Re \lambda(n)\right|\le 2$

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

Can someone help me ? why this should be right ?
For $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}^n$ and $I \subset \mathbb{N}$.

$$\left|\sum_{n \in I} \operatorname{Re}(\lambda(n))\right|\leq 1 ~\text{implies}~ \sum_{n \in I} \left|\operatorname{Re} \lambda(n)\right|\leq 2$$

Comment: What is $\lambda(n)$? Is it a sequence of complex vectors?

Comment: Also, you are using $n$ as the dimension of the complex space, as well as the index of the summations. Please, clarify your question.

Comment: What if take $\lambda_1 = 100$ and $\lambda_2 = -101$ then this does not make sense

Comment: You seem to be using the same letter, $n,$ to refer to two different things.

Comment: Did you mean $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}^{\mathbb{N}}$?

Comment: And should it be $$\Biggl\lvert \sum_{n\in I} \operatorname{Re} \lambda(n)\Biggr\rvert \leqslant 1$$ **for all** $I\subset \mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if take $\lambda(1) = 100 +i$ and $\lambda(2) = -100+\frac12$ and  $\lambda(n) =0$ Every where else  then this does not make sense

Since

$$\left|\sum_{n \in I} \operatorname{Re}(\lambda(n))\right| =|100-100-\frac12|  =\frac12 \leq 1 $$ and $$ 200+\frac12= |100|+|100+\frac12| =\sum_{n \in I} \left|\operatorname{Re} \lambda(n)\right|\leq 2$$
**Which is Heavily absurd**